# Trouble evaluating an expression

Tags: numerical-integration

I am currently trying to numerically evaluate an expression which is the following. The expression `IntD0` is being plotted, but the next line is not. I thought it might be because of zeros in `IntD0` but even after removing them it shows an empty plot. I am not sure why this is happening.

The expression formally is the following :
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&D_0 = \int_{-\left({w}+{T}\right)}^{\left({w}+{T}\right)}d{\epsilon}\frac{1}{\pi{w}}\left[1-\frac{{\epsilon}^2}{{w}^2}\right]\frac{\exp{\left(\frac{{\epsilon}-{\mu}}{{T}}\right)}}{\left(\exp{\left(\frac{{\epsilon}-{\mu}}{{T}}\right)}+1\right)^2}\frac{1}{T} \\
&E = \sqrt{\lambda - \frac{1}{D_{0}}},
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $\lambda$, $w$, $T$, $\mu$ are parameters, and I am plotting $E$ as a function of $T$.

```
g[\[Epsilon]_, w_] := 1/(\[Pi]  w) (1 - (\[Epsilon])^2/w^2)
f1[\[Epsilon]_, \[Mu]_, 
  T_] :=  E^((\[Epsilon] - \[Mu])/T)/((1 + E^((\[Epsilon] - \[Mu])/
    T))^2 T)

(* Integrate*)
IntD0[(w_)?NumericQ, (\[Mu]_)?NumericQ,  (T_)?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  g[\[Epsilon], w] f1[\[Epsilon], \[Mu], T], {\[Epsilon], -w - T, 
   w + T}, MaxRecursion -> 100, AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, 
  Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[Table[{b, IntD0[t, e, b]}, {b, 0.001, 1, 0.05}]], {e, 0,
   1}, {t, 0.001, 1}]

Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[
  Table[{b, Sqrt[c - (1/IntD0[t, e, b]) ]}, {b, 0.1, 1}]], {e, 0.5, 1}, {t, 0.5, 1},{c, 0.5, 1}] (* empty plot*)
```

Edit: I had made an error in not specifying the increments for b. (thanks to @MarcoB for this)

Comment: What's the definition of the function `g` that appears in your `NIntegrate`?

Comment: There is also a mismatch between your Mathematica code `(1+E^((\[Epsilon]-\[Mu])/T))^2` and the denominator in the TeX-formula for $D_0$, the square is not in the same place.

Comment: Indeed sorry for the mistake. @MarcoB sorry I forgot to add that

Comment: `Table[{b, Sqrt[c - (1/IntD0[t, e, b]) ]}, {b, 0.1, 1}]]` Evaluates to a `{{0.1, 0. + 3.01091 I}}`, A single point to plot, but a complex and  `ListLinePlot`expects real numbers, not complex.

Comment: the single point is strange and perhaps the problem. I did realize that I need to take the real part. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Charlie In the Table expression your iteration ranges from 0.1 to 1, without an explicit increment, which indicates a default increment of 1. Therefore, b only takes the very first value and then the iteration stops. Perhaps you meant to include a smaller increment (e.g. `{b, 0.1, 1, 0.1}`)?

Comment: @MarcoB indeed that was the mistake. Thanks. I have voted to close the question on grounds that it is a syntactical mistake on my part from not reading the doc.

Answer (score 5):

I understand that integrating such complex expressions causes certain difficulties. However, I tried to solve the problem in a direct way.

We take the formula for integration by parts:
[image]

```
u = (1 - \[Epsilon]^2/\[Omega]^2 );

v = Exp[(\[Epsilon] - \[Mu])/T ]/(Exp[(\[Epsilon] - \[Mu])/T ]^2 + 1 );

du = D[u, \[Epsilon]];

dv = D[v, \[Epsilon]];
```

We calculate the integral and obtain a relatively compact form:

```
integralbyparts = -(1/(Pi \[Omega] )) 1/
   T  (ReplaceAll[u, \[Epsilon] -> \[Omega] + T] ReplaceAll[
       v, \[Epsilon] -> \[Omega] + T] - 
     ReplaceAll[u, \[Epsilon] -> -(\[Omega] + T)] ReplaceAll[
       v, \[Epsilon] -> -(\[Omega] + T)] - 
     Integrate[du v, {\[Epsilon], -(\[Omega] + T), \[Omega] + T}]) // 
  Simplify
```

!!!IMPORTANT!!! Then we take the formula $E=\sqrt{\lambda-\frac{1}{D_0}}=\sqrt{\lambda-\frac{1}{integral by parts}}$ and substitute the integral by parts instead of $D_0$ by simply copying the result !

```
e[\[Lambda]_, \[Mu]_, T_, \[Omega]_] := 
 Sqrt[\[Lambda] - 
   1/(1/(\[Pi] \[Omega]^3) (-((
         E^((T + \[Mu] + \[Omega])/T) (T + 2 \[Omega]))/(
         1 + E^((2 (T + \[Mu] + \[Omega]))/T))) + (
        E^((T + \[Mu] + \[Omega])/T) (T + 2 \[Omega]))/(
        E^((2 \[Mu])/T) + E^(2 + (2 \[Omega])/T)) - 
        2 (T + \[Omega]) (ArcCot[E^((T + \[Mu] + \[Omega])/T)] + 
           ArcTan[E^((T - \[Mu] + \[Omega])/T)]) + 
        I T (PolyLog[2, -I E^((T - \[Mu] + \[Omega])/T)] - 
           PolyLog[2, I E^((T - \[Mu] + \[Omega])/T)] - 
           PolyLog[2, -I E^(-((T + \[Mu] + \[Omega])/T))] + 
           PolyLog[2, I E^(-((T + \[Mu] + \[Omega])/T))])))]
```

Then we build a graph and play with the parameters:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[e[\[Lambda], \[Mu], T, \[Omega]], {T, 0.1, 5}, 
  PlotRange -> Full, AxesLabel -> Automatic], {\[Lambda], 1, 
  5}, {\[Omega], 0.1, 1}, {\[Mu], 1, 3}]
```

[image]

It would be nice if you could indicate the ranges of these parameters and their physical meaning. Because for some values, the function is not computable and I had to select these values manually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very nice approach. Unfortunately at this point this problem is still in its infancy and I am not too sure myself about the ranges of these parameters. However, I would be happy to add more details about the physical meanings of the parameters in edits.